# Fantasy movie that was animation, I believe

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I watched bit of this movie when I was a kid. One thing I remember is someone battling a large spider. There was a scene underwater or around water as well. This must have been between 2000-2005. I saw this on TV. I'm  not saying it was made that year, though.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.